# How to hardcode / prepopulate LokiJS Database

Tags: lokijs

I'm just starting off with LokiJS and I have one fundamental question I can't wrap my head around:

Is there a way to hardcode a LokiJS database? Or do I have do add all the data via Javascript?

It seems necessary to me, to have something like PHPMyAdmin to inspect/add/delete the actual data in the database, but I have found nothing so far, to do this with a LokiJS database. Isn't this a big loss in usability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lokijs.org

> A fast, in-memory document-oriented datastore for node.js, browser and cordova.

Use cases:

- To achieve database like feature on a limited resources (Raspberry Pi like) device.
- To create secure applications without running an server.
- To persist data and reuse it, for rich feature applications at client side.
- ..

The list can go on up 100 points.

**Big loss in usability?**

> No.

Because it fulfills the purpose for which it is introduced. (In memory datastore)

**Is there a way to hard-code a LokiJS database?**

> Yes.

Create a yourExampleDB.json or yourExampleDB.db file and insert data in a following manner.

```
{
"filename": "yourExampleDB.db",
"collections": [{
    "name": "entries",
    "data": [{
        "id": 17948697,
        "properties": { ... },
        "meta": {
            "revision": 0,
            "created": 1524651771378,
            "version": 0
        },
        "$loki": 1
    }, {
        "id": 17948705,
        "properties": { ... },
        "meta": {
            "revision": 0,
            "created": 1524651771378,
            "version": 0
        },
        "$loki": 2
    },
     ... 
     ...
     ...
    {
        "id": 11699810,
        "properties": { ... },
        "meta": {
            "revision": 0,
            "created": 1524651771402,
            "version": 0
        },
        "$loki": 11299
    }],
    "idIndex": [1, 2, ... 11298, 11299],
    "binaryIndices": {},
    "constraints": null,
    "uniqueNames": [],
    "transforms": {},
    "objType": "entries",
    "dirty": false,
    "cachedIndex": null,
    "cachedBinaryIndex": null,
    "cachedData": null,
    "adaptiveBinaryIndices": true,
    "transactional": false,
    "cloneObjects": false,
    "cloneMethod": "parse-stringify",
    "asyncListeners": false,
    "disableMeta": false,
    "disableChangesApi": true,
    "disableDeltaChangesApi": true,
    "autoupdate": false,
    "serializableIndices": true,
    "ttl": null,
    "maxId": 11299,
    "DynamicViews": [],
    "events": {
        "insert": [null],
        "update": [null],
        "pre-insert": [],
        "pre-update": [],
        "close": [],
        "flushbuffer": [],
        "error": [],
        "delete": [null],
        "warning": [null]
    },
    "changes": []
}, {
    "name": "messages",
    "data": [{
        "txt": "I will only insert into this collection during databaseInitialize.",
        "meta": {
            "revision": 0,
            "created": 1524651771378,
            "version": 0
        },
        "$loki": 1
    }],
    "idIndex": [1],
    "binaryIndices": {},
    "constraints": null,
    "uniqueNames": [],
    "transforms": {},
    "objType": "messages",
    "dirty": false,
    "cachedIndex": null,
    "cachedBinaryIndex": null,
    "cachedData": null,
    "adaptiveBinaryIndices": true,
    "transactional": false,
    "cloneObjects": false,
    "cloneMethod": "parse-stringify",
    "asyncListeners": false,
    "disableMeta": false,
    "disableChangesApi": true,
    "disableDeltaChangesApi": true,
    "autoupdate": false,
    "serializableIndices": true,
    "ttl": null,
    "maxId": 1,
    "DynamicViews": [],
    "events": {
        "insert": [null],
        "update": [null],
        "pre-insert": [],
        "pre-update": [],
        "close": [],
        "flushbuffer": [],
        "error": [],
        "delete": [null],
        "warning": [null]
    },
    "changes": []
}],
"databaseVersion": 1.5,
"engineVersion": 1.5,
"autosave": false,
"autosaveInterval": 5000,
"autosaveHandle": null,
"throttledSaves": true,
"options": {
    "serializationMethod": "normal",
    "destructureDelimiter": "$<\n"
},
"persistenceMethod": "fs",
"persistenceAdapter": null,
"verbose": false,
"events": {
    "init": [null],
    "loaded": [],
    "flushChanges": [],
    "close": [],
    "changes": [],
    "warning": []
},
"ENV": "NODEJS"
```

}

It's a valid example copy of lokijs db.

**something like PHPMyAdmin to inspect/add/delete?**

> No.

**Or do I have do add all the data via JavaScript?**

> Yes

Steps to follow

- Require lokijs module.
- Create a db.
- Create a collection.
- Insert your data.
- Persist it (Manual/Auto)

Hope it helps.